# Web Scraping stocks

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am currently working on a project that deals with web scraping using R. 
It is very basic but I am trying to understand how it works.

I am using Google Stocks as my URL and I am using the Google ticker as my stock I am viewing.

Here is my code:

```
# Declaring our URL variable
google = html("https://www.google.com/searchq=google+stock%5D&oq=google+stock%5D&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60l3.5208j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
# Prints and initializes the data
google_stock = google %>% 
html_nodes("._FOc , .fac-l") %>% 
html_text()

# Creating a data frame table
goggledf = data.frame(table(google_stock))

# Orders the data into highest frequency shown
googledf_order = googledf[order(-googledf$Freq),]

# Displays first few rows of data
head(googledf_order)
```

When I run this I get `integer(0)`, which should be displaying a stock price. 
I am not sure why this is not displaying the correct stock price. 
I also tried running the code up until `html_text()` and it still did not show me the data that I wanted or needed.

I just need this to display the stock price from the web.

I am using `SelectorGadget` to get my html node ("._FOc , .fac-l")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be something wrong with your URL. When I try to paste it into a browser, I get a 404 error.

Instead of scraping you could use the `quantmod` package. To get historical data you could use the following:

```
    library(quantmod)
    start <- as.Date("2018-01-01")
    end <- as.Date("2018-01-20")

    getSymbols("GOOGL", src = "google", from = start, to = end)
```

To get a the current stock quote you could use:

```
    getQuote("GOOGL", src = "yahoo")
```

From the `quantmod` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf), the `getQuote` function "only handles sourcing quotes from Yahoo Finance."